# Ionic Native + IOS + OneSignal

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic2, onesignal, ionic3, ionic-native

need your help I am working with ionic3 + IOS + one signal (notification)

during **ionic cordova plugin add onesignal-cordova-plugin** plugin installation error

**Error**

[image: error]

it is was working fine with android platform.

Comment: _it is was working fine with android platform._ meaning it is already installed?

Comment: 1st  I have tried with android platform so installed for particular android platform and its working fine with android, 
now I am working with IOS platform

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mac user need to install `cocoapods`, e.g.:

`sudo gem install cocoapods`

Answer (score 2):

```
After install latest ionic, 
the problem is solved,
now my updated system info is given bellow

global packages:

@ionic/cli-utils : 1.4.0
Cordova CLI      : 7.0.1 
Ionic CLI        : 3.4.0
local packages:

@ionic/app-scripts              : 1.3.12
@ionic/cli-plugin-cordova       : 1.4.0
@ionic/cli-plugin-ionic-angular : 1.3.1
Cordova Platforms               : none
Ionic Framework                 : ionic-angular 3.5.0
System:

Node       : v6.10.0
OS         : macOS Sierra
Xcode      : Xcode 8.2.1 Build version 8C1002 
ios-deploy : 1.9.1 
ios-sim    : 5.0.13 
npm        : 5.0.3
```